# display loop for in flask template jinja2

Tags: python, flask

hello everyone i am just starting learned python and flask, and i want to display this code in jinja2 template with for loop like in backend , can anyone help me please to display this code below in jinja template like this :

```
entities = client.analyze_entities(document).entities
for entity in entities:
  entity_type = enums.Entity.Type(entity.type)
  print('=' * 20)
  print(u'{:<16}: {}'.format('name', entity.name))
  print(u'{:<16}: {}'.format('type', entity_type.name))
  print(u'{:<16}: {}'.format('salience', entity.salience))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is how you set variables and do for loops in jinja2. As for the prints, are they printing to a console or the html? If you want them rendered to the html, you will have to give id tags where you want them to go. It would make it easier for you to build it on the backend and let the html call a python function to return the print statements to your website.

```
{% block content %}
        {% set  entities = client.analyze_entities(document).entities %}
        {% for entity in entities %}
            {% set entity_type = enums.Entity.Type(entity.type) %}

{% endblock %}
```

Also, you will have problems with the other methods you are calling, like ".analyze_entities". Another reason why doing this in the backend would make it easier for you. Good luck and hope it helped! Feel free to ask more questions if need be.

Comment: they show me this error : jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'enums' is undefined

Comment: it's better if we use a table and send it with all this attributs but i don't know how to do it

Comment: ok, give me a few minutes and I will put an example together. Basically you will set up an api.py file, give the table an id in the html file while also creating the column titles for your table, then at the bottom of the html file, have jinja2 call the javascript, the js will call your api.py and python will hand the results to js, and js will hand it to your html table.